# Result as new argument

Tags: python, loops, output

I wish to repeat this function (say 200times), each time taking the output as a new argument:

```
def coop(url):
    num_body = re.search('\d+', urllib.urlopen(url).read()).group(0)
    num_head = re.search('\d+', url).group(0)
    new = url.replace(num_head, num_body)
    return new
```

Comment: What do you mean by "taking the output as a new argument"? Do you want to call coop(new) at the end?

Comment: yes and i want to do this n times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with a simple loop:

```
for _ in range(0,200):
    url = coop(url)
```

This works with the function you have written ands stores the result in `url` to feed into the next call.